# How to alter my query in hook_views_query_alter to use the right where expression?

Tags: database, views

I am displaying a fee schedule using views and need to skip paid fee schedules. For that, I need to add following JOIN in views query using `hook_views_query_alter()`.

```
LEFT JOIN ic_fee_schedule_payments AS FSP ON fee_schedule.fid = FSP.fid AND fee_schedule_students.uid = FSP.uid AND fee_schedule_instalments.iid = FSP.iid
```

with added where clause as:

```
AND FSP.pid IS NULL
```

I have tried the following code in `hook_views_query_alter()`, but it does not work.

```
# In order to add a new table to join, you'll need to create a new views_join object.
    $join = new views_join;
    $join->construct('fee_schedule', 'fee_schedule_payments', 'fid', 'fid');
    $join1 = new views_join;
    $join1->construct('fee_schedule_students', 'fee_schedule_payments', 'uid', 'uid');
    $join2 = new views_join;
    $join2->construct('fee_schedule_instalments', 'fee_schedule_payments', 'iid', 'iid');
    #$join->extra = array(array('table' => 'fee_schedule_payments', 'field' => 'pid', 'operator' => 'IS', 'value' => 'NULL'));
    // $join is the views_join object created above
    $query->add_relationship('fee_schedule', $join, 'fee_schedule_payments');
    $query->add_relationship('fee_schedule_students', $join1, 'fee_schedule_payments');
    $query->add_relationship('fee_schedule_instalments', $join2, 'fee_schedule_payments');
    $query->add_where('fee_schedule_payments', 'fee_schedule_payments.pid', 'NULL', 'IS');
```

EDIT: Tried the other way but still does not work.

```
$join = new views_join;
    $join->construct('fee_schedule', 'fee_schedule_payments', 'fid', 'fid');
    $join->extra = array(array('table' => 'fee_schedule_payments', 'field' => 'uid', 'operator' => '=', 'value' => 'fee_schedule_students.uid'), array('table' => 'fee_schedule_payments', 'field' => 'iid', 'operator' => '=', 'value' => 'fee_schedule_instalments.iid'));
    $query->add_relationship('fee_schedule', $join, 'fee_schedule_payments');   
    $query->add_where('fee_schedule_payments', 'fee_schedule_payments.pid', 'NULL', 'IS');
```

Am I missing something or need to alter query in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think to add the "IS NULL" part, you may need spaces around "IS" such as:

```
$query->add_where('fee_schedule_payments', 'fee_schedule_payments.pid', 'NULL', ' IS ');
```

OR...maybe something using add_where_expression...

```
$query->add_where_expression(0, 'fee_schedule_payments.pid IS NULL');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8, the following seems to work:

```
$query->addWhere(0,'fee_schedule_payments.pid',NULL,'IS NULL');
```